# Is GDAL/OGR (specifically CoordinateTransformation) thread-safe?

Tags: gdal, ogr, multithreading

I'm using the Java bindings if it matters. I have a heavily multi-threaded program and this is one of the bottlenecks that I have in a synchronization block. If I could remove the synchronization, it would improve speed a bit I believe, but I can't find any information whatsoever whether it's thread-safe or not, or how best to personally test for that.

The specific line would look something like: `FROM_WGS84.TransformPoint(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);` where `FROM_WGS84` is a `CoordinateTransformation` class created using `CoordinateTransformation.CreateCoordinateTransformation()`, but with arguments supplied obviously.

Comment: I think that the best GDAL experts follow gis.stackexchange only occasionally and gdal-dev mailing list may serve you better this time.

Comment: Did you ask? Did you get an answer?